# MySQL: all results in one row

Tags: mysql

I have a DB that keep track of a game. For each user I have a test, for each test I have n missions and for each mission I have n tasks.

I need to do a query that allow me to see in a row the user with every mission and every task for each mission connected to him.

By now I have made a query that make a row for each task, but this result is not acceptable, since I have a lot of rows for each user.

Sorry if my question isn't clear.

My DB

```
user
 UserID
 Name
 Surname,
 SignUpDateTime
 Username
 Password

test
 TestID
 TestDateTime
 USER_UserID

mission
 MissionID
 TEST_TestID
 StartDateTime
 EndDateTime
 CompletionTime
 Difficulty
 Level
 MissionName

task
 TaskID
 CompletionTime
 Errors
 Accuracy
 ReactionTime
 MISSION_MissionID
```

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of GROUP BY and [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) like GROUP_CONCAT()?

Comment: "By now I have made a query that make a row for each task, but this result is not acceptable, since I have a lot of rows for each user." Why isn't this acceptable? It's a much clearer result, and you can always change it around when outputting the data (which you are supposed to do anyway)

Comment: Alex: I'll made some research :) ty

Erik:I think it's better too, but the final users want it in the way I described. I think it's better for some statistic application they're using

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() is not good for me! I don't need to concatenate strings, I need to have different column for each mission and each task! Thank you anyway :)

Comment: It sounds like you're after a (dynamic?) PIVOT QUERY

Comment: That will be a hell of a results table. Are you sure you need this for what you are trying to achieve?